# Making div fit into screen size with zooming out

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this working on a project that convert div into images. everything works but I have having this problem on mobile resizing. anytime the web page loads for the first time I will have to use my hand to zoom in for it to fit mobile screen size. I have several method for it work but is not working. Take a look at my code and see if am doing it right. Am not good with JavaScript if there  a script to get done I will be open to

```
  <div class="container" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
         <div class="col-md-7" style="background-color: #fff;">
            <div id="outer">
              <div class="meme-generator " >
                <div class="meme-generator-wrapper" id="memeGeneratorWrapper">
                  <div id="memeGeneratorImg">
                  </div>
                  <div id="memeOverlay" class="meme-hidden meme-generator-overlay"></div>
                  <h4 class="name" id='outputAccHomePagePermalink'></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="meme-generator-controls">
                  <a class="button button-primary meme-upload" href="#" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight:bold;">
                  <label>
                    <input id="memeAddPhoto" type="file">
                  </label>
                  Add Photo
                  </a>
                  <a class="button button-primary" id="memeClearPhoto" href="#" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight:bold;">Clear Photo</a>
                  <button class="button button-primary" id="foo" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight:bold;">download</button>
                </div>
                <div class="home_page_title">
                  <input id="nameField"  type="text"   name="Accessable[accsc_home_page_title]"   placeholder="Enter Your Name Here" 
                  data-depend-id="accsc_home_page_title" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight:bold; margin-top: 20px;"> 
                </div>
                </div
            </div>
            </div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    .meme-generator-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      width: 492px;
         height: 607px;
      background: url("{% static 'dp.png' %}")  no-repeat center right #222228;
      -webkit-background-size: contain;
      -moz-background-size: contain;
      -ms-background-size: contain;
      background-size: contain;
    }
.meme-generator-overlay {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: url("{% static 'dp.png' %}") no-repeat 0 0;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -ms-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .meme-generator-controls {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .meme-upload {
      position: relative;
    }

    .meme-upload label {
      background: #000;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      -webkit-opacity: 0;
      -moz-opacity: 0;
      -ms-opacity: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    .meme-upload input {
      cursor: pointer !important;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
   .cr-slider-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
   }
   .name{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: bold;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color :#ee2047 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
   }
   .home_page_title input{
    width:71%;
    border: 1px solid #091639;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 30px 60px -12px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 18px 36px -18px;
   }
   .meme-generator-controls .button {
    background-color: #091639;

   }
   .meme-generator-controls .button:hover {
    background-color: #ee2047
   }
   @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .cr-slider-wrap{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 99;
   }

#wrap {
  position: fixed;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#outer {
  left: -20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 180%;
  background: #fff;
  transform-origin: 0% 0%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 25px rgba(223, 207, 207, 0.2);
}
#mob{
  width: 100vh;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using bootstrap, usually you can use the classes:

1. "img-responsive" for bootstrap 3
2. "img-fluid" for bootstrap 4

If you want to scale an image just using CSS though, you can set the max-width to 100% on the image tag. I have included a bootstrap example for using img-fluid on the img tag - Hope it helps :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" >

        <div>
            <img src="img.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">          
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```